# Deploy on heroku with nodeJs : I'm getting 503 Status - Service Unvailable NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm trying to make a deploy using heroku (tutorial repo: https://github.com/l0609890/pern-deploy-tutorial ), the app is uploaded but the server does not work. When i make a get in the URL/route i get:

Status: 503 Service Unvailable.

console:

-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "15.8.0",
    "npm": "7.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "henry",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^7.18.2"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is starting on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Thank you guys for your time!

PD: Build Log

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  15.8.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   7.5.1
       
       Resolving node version 15.8.0...
       Downloading and installing node 15.8.0...
       npm 7.5.1 already installed with node
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 73 packages, and audited 74 packages in 2s
       
       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
       > cd client && npm install && npm run build
       
       
       added 1938 packages, and audited 1939 packages in 55s
       
       131 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       > client@0.1.0 build
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled with warnings.
       
       src/components/EditTodo.js
         Line 12:13:  'res' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
       
       src/components/InputTodo.js
         Line 15:13:  'response' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
       
       src/components/ListTodos.js
         Line 11:13:  'res' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
       
       Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
       To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
         41.97 KB  build/static/js/2.d54cb9f7.chunk.js
         1.34 KB   build/static/js/main.25558235.chunk.js
         773 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.900dd88b.js
         574 B     build/static/css/main.9d5b29c0.chunk.css
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
         yarn global add serve
         serve -s build
       
       Find out more about deployment here:
       
         https://cra.link/deployment
       
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       up to date, audited 74 packages in 712ms
       
       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 81.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://pern-deploy-tutorial-jgp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Procfile in root directory:

```
worker: npm start
```

Comment: do you have a procfile set up as well in your directory?

Comment: did you looked in the log file whats happen there?

Comment: Hi guys, yes I have a file Procfile in root directory and in the build log I don't see anything strange except NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error